# What techniques we should use to prevent our JVM from going OutOfMemory?

Tags: java, spring, memory-management, jvm, inversion-of-control

When we create an object of a class, object will go to the heap and reference variables will placed into the stack.

What I'm trying to ask here is, How many object creation can result in OutOfMemory error and our JVM will run out of memory.

Also, In spring we create objects using dependency injection and then IOC container will creates and manages the them and their life-cycle. So the question is where does all objects gets stored and What are the chances for IOC container to go out of memory.

Is there any limitation?

Comment: *"How many objects can be created?"* That obviously depends on size of object and amount of memory, so what generic answer are you expecting? --- *"Where does all objects gets stored?"* On the heap, as you already said yourself. --- *"What are the chances for IOC container to go out of memory?"* Again, that **obviously** depends on number and size of beans and amount of memory. --- *"Is there any limitation?"* Yes.

Comment: @Andreas What are the limitation then, and does IOC have its own memory area where It stores all the objects or it uses the same heap.

Comment: The limitation is the amount of memory. What other limitation were you expecting? --- The IOC is also Java code, and there is only one heap.

Comment: If you experience an OOM, take a heap snapshot, look for the leak cause, fix it. Speculation about complex applications without data probably is not going to be fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many objects live longer i.e. in some kind of cache etc.
You can get OOM even with objects on stack if you, say, try to load a large table or file in memory.

If you want to prevent OOM, then you should know memory usage of your application.
Use a profiler or APM tool like AppDynamics, Dynatrace or NewRelic to see memory usage patterns, or take few heap dumps and analyze them.

Answer (score 0):

The number of objects you can keep depends on the maximum heap size and the size of each object. For a typical server size of say 4 GB, you can create tens of millions of objects. You are highly unlikely to run out of memory unless you are loading a serious amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

> How many object creation can result in OutOfMemory error and our JVM
>   will run out of memory ?

This depends upon the number of objects and the JVM Heap size configured by default or by configured using `-Xmx` parameter.

> Also, In spring we create objects using dependency injection and then
>   IOC container will creates and manages the them and their life-cycle.
>   So the question is where does all objects gets stored and What are the
>   chances for IOC container to go out of memory ?

Instead of we creating the object manually for a class using `new` operator, we have given the duty to the IOC container (to inject the dependencies in a controlled manner). So, whether we create the object using `new` operator or IOC container create the object, both will ultimately reside inside the JVM.

So, IOC container will manage all of the objects within the JVM only and all objects will be stored in Heap memory and the chances of out of memory depends upon the default or -XmX as mentioned above.

Comment: How does spring differentiate and keeps track of only the objects that are created using spring if all is going to store at one place.